# Bootstrap dropdown items do not align correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a simple webpage that is acting as a front-end for a SQL database. I have not added any custom CSS or any custom code other than plain Bootstrap elements. The dropdown items are not aligned and appear to the right of the actual dropdown button. Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>No Fail Sales Database</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showAbout(){
                $('#aboutModal').modal('toggle');
            }
        </script>

        <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!--------------- BEGIN ABOUT MODAL ---------------------->
        <div class="container" align="center">
            <div id="aboutModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> 
                <div class="modal-dialog"> 
                    <div class="modal-content" >  
                        <div class="modal-header">  
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">About Us</h4>
                        </div>   
                        <div class="modal-body"> 
                            <p class="lead">This site contains a front-end interface for our project: No Fail Sales</p>
                            <p class="lead">Project Members: Anthony Bonarrigo, Brian Keiran, Cesar Nascimento</p>
                        </div> <!--END BODY-->
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div><!--END FOOTER-->
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!------------------------- END ABOUT MODAL --------------------->


        <!------------------------ BEGIN JUMBOTRON/HEADER --------------->
        <div class="jumbotron" id="db_header">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 style="text-align: center">No Fail Sales</h1>
                <p style="text-align: center">A UI for database for No Fail Sales
                    <br><br><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="showAbout()">About</button></p>
                </div>
        </div> 
        <!------------------------END JUMBOTRON ------------------------>

        <!------------------------BEGIN INPUT FIELDS--------------------->
        <div class="container">  
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <h2 style="text-align: center">Query by Product</h2>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input method="GET" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="q_seller" class="col-xs-4" align="center">
                    <h2 style="text-align: center">Query by Seller</h2>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input method="GET" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-----------------END INPUT FIELDS-------------------->

                <!-----------------GENERATE THE DROPDOWN--------------->
                <div class="col-xs-4" align="center">
                    <h2 style="text-align: center">Search by Category</h2>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="categoryDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                        Category
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="categoryDropdown">
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Clothing</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Electronics</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Cleaning Supplies</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Office Supplies</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sports Equipment</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Health and Beauty</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Jewelry</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Automotive</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Food and Drink</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Lawn and Garden</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!----------------END DROPDOWN---------------------->
            </div>
            <!--------------------END INPUT AREA-------------------> 
        </div>

        <!--Placed at end of page so it loads faster-->
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you add a fiddle or bootply? makes it easier for debugging...

Comment: Seems to be working here:  https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6670/

Comment: Agree with @ZachLeighton, it is working for me as well. Maybe we're missing the problem?

Comment: Looks fine to me, too

Comment: After the page reaches a certain width the items stop aligning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dropdown` `<div>` is expanding to the full with of its containing column while the `dropdown-toggle` is not, causing the `dropdown-menu` to align with the column instead of the `button`. This solution isn't general but I think it best for a quick fix like yours:

CSS:

```
.dropdown {
  width: 100px;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
  width: 100%;
}
```

or

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 100px;" class="dropdown">
  <button style="width: 100%;" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="categoryDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
```